# Facebook Android SDK source will not compile with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

After finally getting the Android Facebook SDK to properly import thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375211/difficulty-in-importing-the-facebook-android-sdk-into-eclipse), I found that eclipse does not recognize the override of onclick in FbDialog.java:

```
mCrossImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.onCancel();
        FbDialog.this.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Nor does it recognize the overrides of onServiceConnected and onServiceDisconnected in the TokenRefreshServiceConnection implementation of ServiceConnection

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
    messageSender = new Messenger(service);
    refreshToken();
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg) {
    serviceListener.onError(new Error("Service disconnected"));
    // We returned an error so there's no point in
    // keeping the binding open.
    mAuthActivity.unbindService(TokenRefreshServiceConnection.this);
}
```

All three methods say, in the warning, that the method must override a superclass method. I have not modified the code at all yet. I checked that Eclipse recognizes the types as the same ones in the respective superclasses, and I have tried pressing control-shift-o to organize the imports, which was a fix suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6644262/786020) for a similar problem.

These overrides are part of the SDK, not any separate project. I set up the project to use Android SDK 2.2 as was shown on Facebook's instructions, and 4.0.3, which should be, theoretically, compatible with all previous versions. I have yet to get Facebook's own code to work. As a side note, is there a jar I can use instead? It would make this much easier.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Guessing your Project Properties -> Java Compiler Compiler compliance level is set to 1.5, not 1.6 (or higher).

Change this.

[Why is javac failing on @Override annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation)

Comment: Oh, I thought that I had it on 1.6/1.7. This is the problem I've been having. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The lazy, fast and easy fix is to remove the @Override annotations. The correct fix is to check that the project compiles to Java 1.5 or above, to use "fix project properties" from Eclipse, and possibly to check that the Facebook library project uses the same Android SDK for compiling against, as your project.

Comment: I did that at one point, but that only made it so it could compile, not run. I will edit my post, though, so I can mention that I cannot get the Facebook Android SDK itself to compile, not my project. And I've tried using different SDKs (Specifically, both 2.2, and the latest which should be compatible with all previous, theoretically), none worked.

Comment: have you checked the 'Problems' view from Eclipse? It's not shown by default in Indigo and usually contains all the information you need

Comment: That actually told me nothing that I didn't already see in code. "The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method", "The method onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) of type Facebook.TokenRefreshServiceConnection must override a superclass method", and "The method onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName) of type Facebook.TokenRefreshServiceConnection must override a superclass method".

Comment: Well, I tried removing the Override annotations again, and it worked. Color me crazy, but I was rather certain that abstract methods needed to be declared overridden. Apparently not? I checked where Eclipse thinks it's getting those methods, and it was veritably from the extended abstract classes. Also, both the library and my program work now. My only question is: why can I not use Override in this case, if the code is overriding abstract methods?